# Restore a deleted record with same Id as it has previously, when ID field (PK) is auto increment (MySQL with EF)

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, auto-increment, identity

I'm trying to design a rollback changes system.
I'm tracking old record values when a record id modified or deleted and then I'm using that values to re-insert it when user choose to rollback it...

editions rollback are working as expected.

deletions are not... because when I attach the entity to DBContext it has the old Id but when I execute DbContext.SaveChanges(); the Id is replaced per a new one(Auto Incremented)

Here is the sample code:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(oldValues.OldData, type);
DbSet mySet = this.Set(type);
mySet.Attach(model);
this.Entry(model).State = oldValues.AuditType == 0 ? EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Added;
base.SaveChanges();
```

into model.Id I can see the correct Id before save but after it EF changes it per a new one.

is there anyway to set temporally to keep the current Id instead of generate a new one?

I tried many solutions but none of them works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To disable the Auto Generated Id, you have to run this command in SQL:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [<schema>].[<TableName>] ON;
```

Then you can insert whatever value you want for the PK, assuming it is still available.  However, I don't think EF has a way to do this from code.

I'm not entirely sure this would work, but, in theory, you could run some ad-hoc SQL right before save-changes on a transaction you create and then see if EF will take it.

If that doesn't work, then try this:

```
ALTER TABLE theTableInQuestion AUTO_INCREMENT=1234
```

EIDT: Or try this approach:

[How can I force entity framework to insert identity columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086006/how-can-i-force-entity-framework-to-insert-identity-columns/41675310#41675310)

Comment: I already tried that solution but doesn't seems to work. I get an exception  "Unknown system variable 'IDENTITY_INSERT'" when run this:

Comment: Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Set Identity_Insert " + tableName + "  ON");

Comment: Also I tried to run it directly into workbench and get same error. maybe this MySQL Server version doesn't support that? I'm using 5.6...

Comment: Hmm, another option is to run this query right before instead then:

ALTER TABLE theTableInQuestion AUTO_INCREMENT=1234