# Force entity framework to add identity column

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

This issue is solved for me in this thread 
[How can I force entity framework to insert identity columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086006/how-can-i-force-entity-framework-to-insert-identity-columns/31856991#31856991)

But what I need to know that if I set

```
dataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[User] OFF");
```

before I call the SaveChanges() method will it have the same effect?, I mean why should I turn Identity to off after I call SaveChanges().

Comment: I think it is simple, you are setting the identity and once you are done with your operation, you are again resetting it to have old state for the table. :)

Comment: I know, I'm asking here to reset it back after or before SaveChanges, do they have the same effect to the underlying database?

Comment: The reason I'm asking before or after, because in my case I'm writing into 2 tables at the same time(the second relies on the first) and since you can't set the identity to 2 tables at the same time, I needed to first enable identity for the first table and after I finish i enable the identity for the second table then I call SaveChanges().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing this exact thing a few days ago. Using

```
dataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Table] ON");
```

and

```
dataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Table] OFF");
```

did nothing.

I had to use a SQL Command that turned it on, did what I wanted to do, and then turned it off within the same command.

Comment: To me the solution in the thread I mentioned works perfectly, but here I'm asking whether to set Identity OFF after or before the call of SaveChanges.

Comment: I'll have to have another play, I couldn't get it to work. It stayed as an auto incremental number when using EF. I'd probably say after, until that point everything is held in a buffer. EF does everything in one transaction upon SaveChanges