# How to insert an auto_increment key into SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert rows into a table that has a unique, non auto-incremented primary key.

Is there a native SQL function to evaluate the last key and increment it or do I have to do it in two steps:

```
key = select max(primary.key) + 1

INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE (primary.key, field1, fiels2) VALUES (KEY, value1, value2)
```

Comment: Do you mean you have an [`IDENTITY` column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) on the table? If so, what precise problem are you having that is not discussed in the documentation or the [many questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+identity) on this site about using them? In a comment below you mention an error but you haven't said exactly what it is. Ideally, please show your `CREATE TABLE` script, your `INSERT` statement, and the resulting error message.

Comment: This thread have solved my all headache and code is compiling back. Why ppl does downvoted this?

Comment: Question, answers to it and these comments merely add confusion. Using `SET IDENTITY_INSERT sometableWithIdentity ON` from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7063527/1548275 is a clear approach to problem as I see it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Judging by you comments throughout, you have a primary key on the table that is not an identity column.

If your version of SQL Server is SQL 2012 you should look into sequences: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

In other versions you either need to recreate the table using the IDENTITY property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(v=sql.80).aspx) for the primary key column or use a two step approach.

If you go with the two step approach you need to make sure that concurrently running inserts won't end up using the same new value. The easiest way to do that is this is by combining the select and the insert into one value and using the serializable table hint:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tbl1(id INT PRIMARY KEY, val1 INT, val2 INT)

INSERT INTO dbo.Tbl1(id, val1, val2)
VALUES((SELECT ISNULL(MAX(id)+1,0) FROM dbo.Tbl1 WITH(SERIALIZABLE, UPDLOCK)), 42, 47);

SELECT * FROM dbo.Tbl1;
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Now there's a solution, it´s not a function but I can manage with a sub-querie, better then a two step procedure. Thanks.

Comment: `SERIALIZABLE` is equivalent to `HOLDLOCK` and is a good start but is *not enough*. Your query can still fail with high concurrency. You must add `UPDLOCK, TABLOCKX`. The parts of a query are executed over time, and locks are acquired over time--so the `INSERT` comes after the `SELECT`. Two clients can `SELECT` at the same time with fully compatible read locks, then the second one be blocked while the first one converts to an `UPDLOCK` for its `INSERT`, then the second one has the old value once the block is over. You need the `SELECT` to block **all readers**!

Comment: Ultimately, this `SELECT max() + 1` pattern is not best practice and cannot be recommended. Identity columns exist for precisely this reason. Use them.

Comment: @ErikE, you are right, I forgot the UPDLOCK. I did update the answer. - However, a TABLOCKX is not required. We only need to stop the same query from reading, not any query. Then we only need to make sure that any insert is using this pattern. Concurrent inserts not following this pattern will be blocked by the SERIALIZABLE query hint and eventually fail. - While it is not the best solution, it is a usable one. Sometimes IDENTITY columns are just not an option.

Comment: Yes I was too hasty in suggesting TABLOCKX as the only means to solve the problem. Without it everything will be okay as long as no other query tries to use this pattern not having the right locking.

Comment: This statement is meant to insert records to a ERP data base from an external application, the only that will be using the document series in question, I will be be, on the other hand, running a sync procedure that will do lots of inserts in a roll, what do you reckon?

Comment: If the sync procedure inserts one record at a time you can use the same pattern. If you need to be able to insert several rows in a single insert statement, you can stil use this pattern if you combine it with the ROW_NUMBER() function. Important is that the SELECT max() +1 uses both SERIALIZABLE and UPDLOCK on all(!) inserts to this table. If that select is not a sub-select as in my example you also need to wrap it together with the insert in a transaction (If this happens in a procedure read this first:http://sqlity.net/en/585/how-to-rollback-in-procedures/)

Answer (score 31):

Since it's auto-generated, simply don't provide it:

```
INSERT INTO bo.TABLE (field1, fiels2) VALUES (value1, value2)
```

**Update**: that will work if your column is an `IDENTITY` column.

To provide explicit values to an identity column, you have to do this:

```
set identity_insert bo.TABLE on

INSERT INTO bo.TABLE (primary_key, field1, fiels2) VALUES ((SELECT ISNULL(MAX(id) + 1, 0) FROM bo.Table), value1, value2)

set identity_insert bo.TABLE off
```

But there's no compelling reason for doing it this way.

Comment: I've tried it,  throws a constraint error, I have to provide the value.

Comment: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'pk_bo'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.bo'. The duplicate key value is (921, 0, 2012).

Comment: @RubenTeixeira That's the error you get when you DON'T specify the ID?  You sure it doesn't have an identity column?

Comment: the db as another two primary keys the document series number and the year, when I don't provide a the key for the document number it throws this error

Comment: Looks like your auto-incremented field is not part of the primary key. Can you post the table definition and your insert statements?

Comment: This is a ERP data base, it has triggers, procedures and the whole nine yards. It works fine when I provide a unique key, I have to provide it.

Comment: I've checked it, it's not a `IDENTITY` column.

Comment: Then it's not auto-incremented.

Comment: Yeah, you can insert to an identity column manually, but if the identity column is `id`, then *why on earth would you manually select the next `id` instead of just inserting*???

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion the best answer is to fix your table so that the PK column is an identity column. (Please see my comments on the answer from Sebastian Meine about why your currently selected answer is not best.) The only way to make an existing PK become an identity column is by swapping out the table. Roughly:

```
BEGIN TRAN;
-- Rename all constraints in original table
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.YourOriginalTable.PK_ConstraintName', 'PKConstraint_Backup';
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.YourOriginalTable.OtherConstraintName', 'OtherConstraintName_Backup';
CREATE TABLE dbo.WorkTable (
    YourPKColumn int identity(1, 1) NOT NULL -- your PK converted to identity
    CONSTRAINT PK_YourOriginalTableConstraintName PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    AllOtherColumns -- all your other columns exactly as in the original table
);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.WorkTable ON;
INSERT dbo.WorkTable (YourPKColumn, AllOtherColumns)
SELECT YourPKColumn, AllOtherColumns
FROM dbo.YourOriginalTable WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.WorkTable OFF;

-- Drop all FK constraints from other tables pointing to your table
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableWithFK_1
DROP CONSTRAINT FK_TableWithFK_1_YourOriginalTableSomethingID;

-- Swap out the tables
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.YourOriginalTable', 'YourOriginalTableBackup';
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.WorkTable', 'YourOriginalTable';

-- If you didn't add them in the WorkTable creation,
-- add all other removed or needed constraints creation
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourOriginalTable
ADD CONSTRAINT OriginalConstraint (OriginalConstraintColumns);
-- Add back FK constraints from other tables to this one.
COMMIT TRAN;
```

You now have a table that has an identity column with a clustered PK on it. You can insert to it no problem. No more concurrency issues and silly `SELECT Max() + 1` junk that is **so easy to get wrong**.

Comment: +1 of course if this is an active system you'll want to do this in an explicit transaction. Otherwise there is danger of getting some data into `YourOriginalTable` after the `INSERT` but before the renames.

Comment: Sorry It´s not my Db, I can't make any changes, it was design to work with a ERP application. Just need to do the procedure explained in the question, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**Inserting one record:**

I only do this to insert a row into a table with a non auto-incremented primary key:

```
DECLARE @myKey int
SET @myKey = (SELECT  ISNULL(MAX(primaryKey),0) FROM dbo.myTable)

INSERT INTO dbo.myTABLE (primaryKey, field1, fiels2) VALUES (@myKey + 1, value1, value2)
```

**Inserting multiple records:**

In another situation, I needed to duplicate multiple records in a table. For this, I used an INSERT from the result of a SELECT.
My intention was to duplicate some records from myTable, that meet a specific condition.
But I needed to figure out how to duplicate records in a table with a unique PRIMARY KEY, without repeating an ID.
Here's how I solved it:

```
DECLARE @myKey int 
SET @myKey = (SELECT  ISNULL(MAX(primaryKey),0) FROM dbo.myTable)

INSERT INTO dbo.myTABLE (primaryKey, field1, fiels2) 
SELECT 
     (primaryKey + @myKey, value1, value2) 
        FROM dbo.myTable 
        WHERE value2 = especific_Condition
```

There were some gaps in the IDs, but I enforce uniqueness PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 0):

create table if not exists Emp
(
  eid int(10) not null primary key auto_increment,
  name varchar(45) not null,
  age int(5) default 20,
  salary int(5)
)
insert into emp values(102,'Ranjan',21,450000);

Then try below sql query .  It will automaticaly increment the ***eid*** to next number .

insert into emp (name,salary) values( 'Lisma',118500);

select * from emp;