# ArcGIS SQL Server ArcSDE: Versioning vs Identity Column

Tags: sql-server, auto-increment, arcgis, identity-column

[I am asking here instead of GIS Stackexchange because this maybe more of a SQL Server issue?]

I have SQL Server ArcSDE connection in which data is batch inserted via some scripts. Currently, anytime there is a new row of data then an '`OBJECTID`' column, set to `INT` and `Identity` Column increases by number 1. So far so good. Except I need to enable "versioning" on the table.

And so I follow this: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n000000v3000000

but get errors because ArcGIS is complaining about the Identity column, per: http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40329 ; and when I remove the Identity attribute to the column then the column value becomes NULL--not good.

So, in my scenario, how I can I increase the value of OBJECTID by 1 number as auto-increment? I supposed, I can just insert some GUID into the 'OBJECTID' field through the script? Also, if I follow the GUID route then I am not sure if I will be able to add rows manually via ArcGIS Desktop on occasional basis?

Thanks!

***Update 1*** Okay, so changed the OBJECTID field to a 'uniqueidentifier' one with a default GUID value and now I am able to enable "versioning" using ArcGIS Desktop. However, ArcGIS is expecting GUID to be an INT data type--and so no go?

Answer (score 0):

In light of my "update 1" in the Question above I managed to take care of this by inserting an INT value for OBJECTID during the batch insertions per the following: [How to insert an auto_increment key into SQL Server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994736/how-to-insert-an-auto-increment-key-into-sql-server-table)

so per the above link, I ended doing:

```
INSERT INTO bo.TABLE (primary_key, field1, fiels2) VALUES ((SELECT ISNULL(MAX(id) + 1, 0) FROM bo.Table), value1, value2)
```

EXCEPT in my case the IDENTITY remains **not** 'ON' at all either in the database or, unlike the above link, I didn't have to set Identity On/Off during batch insertions; Works for some reasons anyway!