# Seeking clarity on auto-id incrementing on duplicate record entry attempt in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I'm aware of SQL Server 2012's behavior of incrementing an auto-ID field even on a duplicate record or failed attempt. From my research, most people say "this shouldn't matter" and that I "shouldn't worry about the auto-ID field" as it's meant for "INSERT attempt" tracking purposes.

In an application I am working on, I am polling a web service periodically and retrieving a handful of "events." I attempt an INSERT of these into a database after each poll. If a duplicate record already exists, it is incrementing my ID field by 1 for each event that is already stored (expected).

I know one solution is to perform a "check" to see if it exists first, but this obviously increases the DB hits dramatically (1 for each event). I've currently wrapped my INSERT in a TRY/CATCH and it solves this problem, but also makes it hard to know if an INSERT actually took place or not in my application.

My question/concern - If this polling happens frequently (every few seconds or so) and I'm doing it for about 300 concurrent web service calls, the ID field will be a huge number fairly quickly. Does this even matter? Should I care? What will happen when it reaches its maximum value in the database?

Comment: Depends how large the table is.  You could load a good chunk of it in memory and then compare against it on every request, refreshing after batch updates.  Otherwise you could insert a specific row id even with auto increment enabled:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994736/how-to-insert-an-auto-increment-key-into-sql-server-table

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the datatype you chose for the auto-increment column as to how large it will get.  An int will go to 2,147,483,647; a bigint to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

As for what happens when you run out (reaches max value)?  It should throw an arithmetic overflow error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to choose your datatype as numeric(38,0) so that you can store a maximum of 38 digits. Anyhow if you reach the maximum value in the DB then you will get the Arithmetic overflow error as per @JLB answer.

Please try the demo here

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (col INT);

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES (1234567890)

--successfull
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES (12345678901)
    --Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 10
    --Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```