# Auto Increment in an INSERT Command

Tags: sql

I have a table that I'm trying to insert new rows into, but there is a column that doesn't auto increment on it's own. Is there a way to write an INSERT command that will auto increment a column depending on the highest value in that column?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (Sql server, mysql, oracle, postgres, etc.)?

Comment: Add query and table structure to question that you tried?

Comment: please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994736/how-to-insert-an-auto-increment-key-into-sql-server-table

Answer (score 0):

I think using a subquery is what you're looking for.
Depending if you're using MySql or SqlServer, or any other type, consider making the adaptations required. Altering the table to make it auto-increment would be the easiest method.

A MySql example is below:

```
INSERT INTO tableinquestion (id, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (((SELECT id FROM tableinquestion ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1)+1), value2, value3, ...);
```

Comment: you should increment too

Comment: where is the increment!

Comment: @Saif edited the answer. Just select the latest ID and add +1 and there's the 'increment'.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to alter table and add identity. This will do the job

```
ALTER TABLE yourTableName
ADD ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY
```