# Updating Identity Column of a table with consecutive numbers through SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

After deleting the duplicate records from the table,
I want to update Identity column of a table with consecutive numbering starting with 1. Here is my table details

```
id(identity(1,1)),
EmployeeID(int),
Punch_Time(datetime),
Deviceid(int)
```

[image]

I need to perform this action through a stored procedure.
When i tried following statement in stored procedure

```
DECLARE @myVar int
        SET @myVar = 0
        set identity_insert TempTrans_Raw# ON
        UPDATE  TempTrans_Raw# SET  @myvar = Id = @myVar + 1
        set identity_insert TempTrans_Raw# off
```

gave error like...Cannot update identity column 'Id'
Anyone please suggest how to update Identity column of that table with consecutive numbering starting with 1.

Comment: identity was never meant to be used as a serial number and continuity is never guaranteed. If you really need a serial number, try adding another column and populating it

Comment: @Raj : other than a new coulmn is there any other solution?

Comment: you can drop and recreate the column, but if you don't care for the content, why do you need that column ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063501/how-to-turn-identity-insert-on-and-off-using-sql-server-2008

Comment: your update statement like below

SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename ON

UPDATE STATEMENT

SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename OFF

Comment: i am getting duplicate records in that table so after deleting identity column is like this way

Comment: i already tried SET IDENTITY_INSERT on then update then SET IDENTITY_INSERT off ....

Comment: Why oh why oh why? Is that column a primary key? I hope not or your database model is taking Tyson style hits to the face.

Comment: 1. Create a new column and update it with serial number
2. Drop the existing column
3. Rename the new column with existing column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDENTITY keword is used to generate a key which can be used in combination with the PRIMARY KEY constraint to get a technical key. Such keys are *technical*, they are used to link table records. They should have no other meaning (such as a sort order). SQL Server does not guarantee the generated IDs to be consecutive. They do guarantee however that you get them in order. (So you might get 1, 2, 4, ..., but never 1, 4, 2, ...)

Here is the documentation for IDENTITY: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186775.aspx.

Personally I don't like it to be guaranteed that the generated IDs are in order. A technical ID is supposed to have no meaning other then offering a reference to a record. You *can* rely on the order, but if order is information you are interested in, you should *store* that information in my opinion (in form of a timestamp for example).

If you want to have a number telling you that a record is the fifth or sixteenth or whatever record in order, you can get always get that number on the fly using the ROW_NUMBER function. So there is no need to generate and store such consecutive value (which could also be quite troublesome when it comes to concurrent transactions on the table). Here is how to get that number:

```
select
  row_number() over(order by id),
  employeeid,
  punch_time,
  deviceid
from mytable;
```

Having said all this; it should never be necessary to change an ID. It is a sign for inappropriate table design, if you feel that need.

Answer (score 5):

```
--before running this make sure Foreign key constraints have been removed that reference the ID. 

--insert everything into a temp table
SELECT (ColumnList) --except identity column
INTO #tmpYourTable
FROM yourTable

--clear your table
DELETE FROM yourTable
-- reseed identity
DBCC CHECKIDENT('table', RESEED, new reseed value)
--insert back all the values 
INSERT INTO yourTable (ColumnList)
SELECT OtherCols FROM #tmpYourTable
--drop the temp table
DROP TABLE #tmpYourTable
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need sequential numbers, may I suggest that you create a table ("OrderNumbers") with valid numbers, and then make you program pick one row from OrderNumbers when you add a row to yourTable.

If you everything in one transaction (i.e. with Begin Tran and Commit) then you can get one number for one row with no gabs.

You should have either Primary Keys or Unique Keys on both tables on this column to protect against duplicates.

HIH,
Henrik

Answer (score -1):

Check this function: `DBCC CHECKIDENT('table', RESEED, new reseed value)`