# Re-structure sequence in existing SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a SQL Server 2016 table and it has than 10,000 rows. The `Id` column is a sequential id incremented by 1. But that `Id` is not in the correct order as shown in the screenshot below where 330 is missing. Is there any way to correct this sequence in an existing table?

[image]

I've tried like below but it's not working.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE contacts_seq
AS BIGINT
   START WITH 1
   INCREMENT BY 1
   MINVALUE 1
   MAXVALUE 99999
   NO CYCLE
   CACHE 10;
```

Comment: you have to ask yourself why the value of a surrogate key would matter? Hint: it doesn't.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819849/updating-identity-column-of-a-table-with-consecutive-numbers-through-sql-stored

Answer (score 1):

There is no point of `fixing` this - you are going to perform a operation which will block the access to your table and may affect your application performance.

And then, someone can delete the record `X` and you will be at the same position again.

Generally, the perpouse of `id` is to uniquely identify a row. If for some visualization reasons you do not want to have `gaps` you can use [RANKING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) functions to `fix` this.

For example:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY id) AS [ID]
```