# Copying data from a table with auto increment column

Tags: sql, sql-server, auto-increment

I have a table in SQL Server with data that has an auto-increment column. The data in the auto increment column is not sequential. It is like `1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9` (missing 4 and 8).

I want to copy the exact data in this table to another fresh and empty identical table. The destination table also has an auto increment column.

Problem: when I copy the data using the query below, the `AttachmentID` has new and different values

```
INSERT INTO FPSDB_new.dbo.Form_Attachment
    SELECT
        CategoryID
    FROM
        FPSDB.dbo.Form_Attachment
```

the `Form_Attachment` table in destination and source is same as below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Form_Attachment] 
(
    [AttachmentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryID]   [int] NULL
)
```

Is there a SQL query solution to make the two tables with identical data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can insert into an `IDENTITY` column by using `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` in your transaction (don't forget to turn it off afterwards):

[How to turn IDENTITY_INSERT on and off using SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063501/how-to-turn-identity-insert-on-and-off-using-sql-server-2008)

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT FPSDB_new.dbo.Form_Attachment ON

INSERT INTO FPSDB_new.dbo.Form_Attachment ( AttachmentID, CategoryID )
SELECT
    AttachmentID,
    CategoryID
FROM
    FPSDB.dbo.Form_Attachment

SET IDENTITY_INSERT FPSDB_new.dbo.Form_Attachment OFF
```

Comment: your answer is correct but if I have data inside the Destination table and I want to replace the rows with that of Source table. Then how can I update the rows of the destination table

Comment: @shomaail you will need to `DELETE` matching rows first. Alternatively look at the `MERGE` operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

1. Drop the copy table
2. Create as select, which will copy the exact structure and data to the new table.

   ```
   Select * 
   into new_table  
   from old_table
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command: SET IDENTITY_INSERT to ON