# how to move record from one database to another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

I have two database,where two table are same with all schema.
I want to move specific records of employees and employeesrates with all columns of both tables.
below is the query.

```
CREATE TABLE #emp
(
empID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) primary key ,
Firstname varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE #empRates
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) primary key ,
empid int, -- foreign key from #emp
rate decimal(10,3),
startdate datetime,
enddate datetime,
);
insert into #emp (firstname) values('First')
insert into #emp (firstname) values('Second')
insert into #emp (firstname) values('Third')

insert into #empRates(empid,rate,startdate,enddate) values(1,10,'2020/01/10','2020/01/20')
insert into #empRates(empid,rate,startdate,enddate) values(1,15,'2020/01/20','2020/01/30')

insert into #empRates(empid,rate,startdate,enddate) values(2,10,'2020/01/10','2020/01/20')
insert into #empRates(empid,rate,startdate,enddate) values(3,15,'2020/01/20','2020/01/30')


select * from #emp
select * from #empRates

drop table #emp
drop table #empRates
```

Here both database on same server. Database1 and Database2. 
below my query which tried.

```
insert into database2..empRates(empid,rate,startdate,enddate) select empid,rate,startdate,enddate
```

from database1..empRates

Here my problem is both database have different records,so identity are different,so after insert other employee rates get displayed for another like mashed up.
I am using sql server 2012.
can you please provide the way.

Comment: You could only do that if firstname is unique in your tables otherwise there is no relationship between them.

Comment: This sort of task is facilitated when tables have a natural key instead of or in addition to the identity surrogate key.

Comment: So you need to copy the records to some sort of temporary table first, and do a mapping between old and new ids, so that empRates can be inserted with ids that match emp?

Comment: Actually duplicate is not an issue, issue is that if I I am moving employee from database1 to database2 , in database2 same identity may be already occupied by another employee.so after import in database2 **empRates** may be wrong-inserted for oher employee.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this post --> [How to turn IDENTITY_INSERT on and off using SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063501/how-to-turn-identity-insert-on-and-off-using-sql-server-2008)

This way you can specify value for id column during insert, so rows on destination databases will keep IDs from origin.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Actually duplicate is not an issue, issue is that if I I am moving employee from database1 to database2 , in database2 same identity may be already occupied by another employee.so after import in database2 **empRates** may be wrong-inserted for oher employee.