# Spring Batch : Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am working on the spring batch application which inserts the new entry into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE internally. Version of spring is 2.2.1 and database is Azure.
While running the job I am getting the below error. As suggested in one of the site, I enabled the SET IDENTITY_INSERT to ON even though I have not used any INSERT statements to BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE. But it is of no use.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:247) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:862) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:917) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:922) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:120) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:140) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn IDENTITY\_INSERT on and off using SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063501/how-to-turn-identity-insert-on-and-off-using-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @mahmoud - i can not use that as i do not use any insert statements. Insert is called internally by spring batch.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SQL server, but according to the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15, "At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT property set to ON". So apparently it is not possible to set this flag once on all Spring Batch tables.. This is really an annoying constraint, and I don't see how this problem could be fixed since Spring Batch won't be able to insert records in its meta-data tables..

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you post your Job configuration...
DataIntegrityViolationException clearly states that an attempt to insert or update data results in violation of an integrity constraint.
[DataIntegrityViolationException Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataIntegrityViolationException.html)

While job configuration `jobBuilderFactory.get(JOB_NAME).incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())`

to increment the run id and every run gets the unique id