# When should I use SET IDENTITY_INSERT <tablename> OFF function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, identity-column

To insert values into the identity column manually, I use:

```sql
SET identity_insert product ON

INSERT INTO product (PID, ProdName, Qty, Unitprice) 
VALUES (10, 'soap', 5400, 22)
```

Firstly I have deleted the 10th row/record, then I have used this command to insert the identity value and record it manually.
this command is inserting the record. It's fine

Where should I write the command `SET identity_insert product OFF`? And what is the use of the `SET identity_insert product OFF` command?

Comment: [[tag:sql-server]] and [[tag:sqlite]] are completely different products; which are you *really* using. The use of `GO` suggests an IDE like SSMS or ADS; which is normally used for SQL Server.

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: @Larnu I am using SQL Server

Comment: @IMSoP where should i use this function 
SET identity_insert product OFF
 and what is use of this function?

Comment: See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7063527/12859753) to [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7063501/12859753)

Comment: *"where should i use this function"* `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` isn't a function. A function would be like `GETDATE()` or `ISNULL()`. As for how to use it, have you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? What about it didn't you understand, so we can try to elaborate.

Comment: @Bill to be fair, that shows how to do it, but I feel like this question asks _why_.

Comment: Aside: The Real Question℠ is why do you want to override an `identity` column? In general you shouldn't be concerned about what identity value is assigned to a row. If there is some reason that a deleted row's identity value _must_ be reused then perhaps you have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql):

> At any time, only one table in a session can have the `IDENTITY_INSERT` property set to `ON`.

So, if you are in a batch where you want to override the auto-generated identity values on *two different* tables, you would set the first one to `OFF` before setting the second one to `ON`.

(Also, like a lot of things, if you change something from the default, it's never a bad idea to change it back.)

Answer (score 1):

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

> At any time, only one table in a **session** can have the IDENTITY_INSERT
> property set to ON. **If a table already has this property set to ON,
> and a SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON statement is issued for another table,
> SQL Server returns an error message** that states SET IDENTITY_INSERT is
> already ON and reports the table it is set ON for.

so you should set it off before you set it on to another table in your session.

Comment: can I insert two or more records at a time for 1 table in the identity column?


SET identity_insert product ON

INSERT INTO product (PID, ProdName, Qty, Unitprice) 
VALUES (10, 'soap', 5400, 22)

INSERT INTO product (PID, ProdName, Qty, Unitprice) 
VALUES (11, 'pencil', 4400, 12)

go

SET identity_insert product OFF

Comment: yes, the number of inserts is not limited by the SET operation.