# SET IDENTITY_INSERT Inside my parameter it does not work

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert values into a table with an identity, I know I have to use before insert: `SET IDENTITY_INSERT`.

What I executed:

```
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(200), @QUERY NVARCHAR(500)
SET @TABLE_NAME = 'devListaTrabajo'
SET @QUERY = 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @TABLE_NAME  + ' ON'
PRINT @QUERY 
EXEC (@QUERY)

    INSERT INTO devListaTrabajo
        (lisId,lisDescripcion,lisEstado,topId,parCLS,parcod)
    VALUES (1,'H',1,1,'H','LH')
```

And my result:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT devListaTrabajo ON
Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 79
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'devListaTrabajo' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbFMd.png)

If you ask me why I don't use the normal statement without the query inside parameter, it is because I plan to do a cycle where the table is changed, and I intend to use the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT`.

Maybe I'm skipping some SQL rule for the use of this statement. Please, I ask for an explanation or another alternative to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of the `EXEC()` command run in a separate context from the rest of the code. That context runs, completes, and you return to original context where identity insert was never changed.

If you want to make this happen dynamically like that, you must put the *entire statement* into the `@QUERY` variable.

Comment: See also [What is the scope of SET IDENTITY_INSERT xyz ON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791941/what-is-the-scope-of-set-identity-insert-xyz-on)

Comment: Excellent, I already included the insert inside the query and it ran perfectly, thank you!