# Is there any issue with Identity Insert. Do other concurrent operations without it goes fine or do it create slowness or deadlocks?

Tags: sql-server

Is there any issue with Identity Insert. Do other concurrent operations without it goes fine or do it create slowness or deadlocks?

I want to to keep moving data with old primary keys and want to keep inserting data with new keys as well.

thanks in advance

Comment: `IDENTITY` and deadlocks have no relation.

Comment: I sure hope there isn't an issue with `IDENTITY INSERT`.  I'm screwed if there is.  If you're worried about PK violations on an `IDENTITY` column, well, when using `IDENTITY INSERT` you should be attentive to that and your code should be such that it accounts for that possibility.  It's up to you to make sure you're not creating such an issue.  In general you should be fine as long as you're not inserting values higher than the current `IDENTITY` seed or that already exist.

Comment: @squillman I agree and I am thinking to experiment  it to make sure it works without issues

Comment: What code do you have that you are worried about?

Comment: its about concept, lot of insertions to be coming from new web app and at same time data for some old clients is moved from old app

Comment: I have given jump to identity for new insertions and old data is being added from old forms in old table and is only copied with old ids

Comment: But moving the old data is a one-time migration process, is it not? Even if it occurs over an "extended" period of time. Use of identity_insert will [create a schema-stability lock](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68058/how-does-identity-insert-affect-concurrency) which can affect concurrency depending on the queries. But this is easily tested and I suggest you try it.

Comment: not 1 time process but can last for 6 months maybe

Comment: after that every customer will be moved to new technology

Comment: And again - this is something easily tested. Whether it affects your processes we cannot guess. It is unlikely in a general sense but no one knows your code and how safe / well-written it is. And if you are doing this for one table, it seems likely that you need to do this for other tables as well. SO is not well-suited to general questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identity insert work independently with concurrent operations since it is not global and is session based, so other query sessions will keep working and generating same output weather its on in 1 session or off

More this is explained here

[What is the scope of SET IDENTITY_INSERT xyz ON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791941/what-is-the-scope-of-set-identity-insert-xyz-on)

It also not created any slowness and deadlocks